# How to use certfp with IRC::Client

Tags: irc, raku

I've used [`IRC::Client`](https://github.com/zoffixznet/perl6-IRC-Client) for a number of IRC bots so far, and I would like to use it for a new project too. However, this time I will need to have the bot authenticate using [certfp](https://www.darenet.org/help/guides/certfp-authentication). [A search for "certfp" on the module's GitHub repository](https://github.com/zoffixznet/perl6-IRC-Client/search?q=certfp&unscoped_q=certfp) yields no results.

Is it possible to configure `IRC::Client` with a certificate so I can make my next IRC bot authenticate using certfp, and if so, how would I go about it?